# Does clusterMap in Snow support dynamic processing?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, snow

It seems clusterMap in Snow doesn't support dynamic processing. I'd like to do parallel computing with two pairs of parameters stored in a data frame. But the elapsed time of every job vary very much. If the jobs are run un-dynamically, it will be time consuming.

e.g.

```
library(snow)
cl2 <- makeCluster(3, type = "SOCK") 
df_t <- data.frame (type=c(rep('a',3),rep('b',3)), value=c(rep('1',3),rep('2',3)))
clusterExport(cl2,"df_t")
clusterMap(cl2, function(x,y){paste(x,y)},
           df_t$type,df_t$value)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that `clusterMap` doesn't support dynamic processing, but there is a comment in the code suggesting that it might be implemented in the future.

In the meantime, I would create a list from the data in order to call `clusterApplyLB` with a slightly different worker function:

```
ldf <- lapply(seq_len(nrow(df_t)), function(i) df_t[i,])
clusterApplyLB(cl2, ldf, function(df) {paste(df$type, df$value)})
```

This was common before `clusterMap` was added to the snow package.

Note that your use of `clusterMap` doesn't actually require you to export `df_t` since your worker function doesn't refer to it.  But if you're willing to export `df_t` to the workers, you could also use:

```
clusterApplyLB(cl2, 1:nrow(df_t), function(i){paste(df_t$type[i],df_t$value[i])})
```

In this case, `df_t` must be exported to the cluster workers since the worker function references it.  However, it is generally less efficient since each worker only needs a fraction of the entire data frame.

Comment: I do appreciate your answer. It is so helpful, not only solving my problem but also enlightening me.

Answer (score 0):

I found clusterMap in Parallel package support LB. But it less efficient than the method of clusterApplyLB combined with lapply implemented by Snow. I tried to find out the source code to figure out. But the clusterMap is not available when I click the link **'source'** and **'R code'**.

[image: Parallel Doc]

Comment: If you want to see the source for `clusterMap` in the parallel package, just execute `library(parallel); clusterMap`.